# React Native app crashes on Windows after adding Firebase login page on Mac

Tags: firebase, react-native, authentication

We are beginners working on a React Native app with a team of developers, some of whom are using Macs and others using Windows machines. Recently, one of our developers working on a Mac added a new login page to the app that links with Firebase for authentication. The app runs fine on the Mac, but when the Windows developers try to run the app, it crashes with an error [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcOzQ.png)

Has anyone else experienced similar issue knowing that it's working fine in MAC developers. I'm stuck and need any suggestions

We tried to run the app in another MacOS and it works fine but unfortuntly it was not working in widnows

Comment: Did you follow the firebase setup for both android and ios? Also you'll need to do the same for other native modules that the login page uses

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution it was related to the styling of the login page one of the dev was using tailwind in the wrong way